# getting errors when using composer to install skywalker/boostcake plugin

Tags: cakephp, plugins

I'm using cakephp v3 and wish to use skywalker/boostcake. This is a twbs helper. I've followed the instructions for composer but keep getting the following error:

[RuntimeException]
Unable to get primary namespace for package slywalker/boost_cake.
Ensure you have added proper 'autoload' section to your plugin's config as
stated in README on https://github.com/cakephp/plugin-installer

I'm obviously doing something wrong or the vendor has missed some vital instructions.

I've tried adding a json string to cakes composer.json file along the lines of:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "src",
        "Skywalker\\BoostCake"\\: "src"
    }
},
```

but no success. Any help appreciated

Comment: Is that really what you are seeing in the RunTimeException or is this just mispelled here? `slywalker/boost_cake`.... should say `skywalker/boost_cake`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides the spelling mistake in the imaginary namespace which says `Skywalker`, and the fact that the path would have to point to something like `vendor/slywalker/boostcake` instead of `src`, that plugin is for CakePHP 2.x, so it will never work.

You may want to check other CakePHP 3.x compatible plugins like for example **https://github.com/friendsofcake/bootstrap-ui**

Comment: Thanks for the info. I've just installed the [holt59 bootstrap helper][1] which seems to be working fine. I will certainly try out the friendsofcake helper if this one does not meet my requirements.
Thanks again.

  [1]: https://github.com/Holt59/cakephp3-bootstrap3-helpers